# Weird file dialogs under MacOSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, jna

I'm trying to build a basic dynamic library for OS X that simply displays a dialog for opening files.
My code looks something like this:

```
NSOpenPanel * dlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
...//setting title and other properties for dlg

dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    resButton = [dlg runModal];
});
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
if (resButton == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)//resButton is global
{...}
```

Now while this basically works, everything is a little bit off:

-The dialog never quite initializes twice the same way (different initial directories, layout mode...).

-Sometimes the initial directory is shown as being empty until I select another one and the first one again.

-"right click" menu won't show.

-Scrolling bounce back effect doesn't work (!!!). I can scroll downwards indefinitely until everything disappears.

-In column mode, previews do not work (the loading icon turns forever) although when viewing in large icon mode, images have their proper preview.

It's like there is a whole update thread that's not running. It's probably linked to the weird context in which the lib is called: from a java program using JNA. But I'm hoping maybe someone knows of a little trick that could fix things, like "just call [system startUpdateTask]" or something :)

Thanks for any help

Comment: What happens if you replace all the `dispatch_` code with just the body of your block `resButton = [dlg runModal];`? `runModal` is a synchronous call after all...

Comment: @CRD Without the dispatch stuff it crashes with an exception where appkit complains that I'm not using "thread 0"

Comment: You need to call this from the main thread... not sure why you'd use a dispatch queue. Use performSelectorOnMainThread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(After comment response:)

Something for you to try (I can't test your scenario). `NSOpenPanel`/`NSSavePanel` are very delicate classes since the introduction of sandbox and need to be handled with care.

All UI operations need to be performed on the main thread, as you have discovered. However instead of using the `dispatch_*` functions try using a synchronous `performSelectorOnMainThread`:

```
NSOpenPanel * dlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
... //setting title and other properties for dlg

resButton = [dlg performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(runModal)
                                  withObject:nil
                               waitUntilDone:YES];

if (resButton == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) //resButton is global
{...}
```

That may solve your issue, or not...

**Addendum**

My bad, as you correctly point out `performSelectorOnMainThread` doesn't return a value. You can instead:

Add `resButton` as an instance variable to your class.

Add the method:

```
- (void) myRunModal:(NSOpenPanel *)dlg
{
   resButton = [dlg runModal];
}
```

Change the code to:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myRunModal:)
                       withObject:dlg
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Or something similar.

Comment: Unfortunately performSelectorOnMainThread has a return type of void and you can't have resButton = [...] like in your example.

Comment: I just tested without assigning resButton (so I don't know if the user hits OK or Cancel)... and it works! That is, everything behaves normally. I guess I can use callbacks or whatever to differentiate between Ok and cancel. Thanks alot!

Comment: @schmop - Apologies, I should not write code directly into answers! Adding addenudum...